# JS error appearing only on Spring Samsung Galaxy SIII

Tags: javascript, android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

We have a signup page with in our app written in HTML in a WebView.  We're seeing a repeat of the following error come up all the time:

```
 window.onerror: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '2' in .@.
```

We've been able to infer that it happens almost strictly on the Spring Samsung Galaxy SIII.  I've tested it on a Verizon SIII and didn't have any problems.  Once the error occurs, the user is stuck on the signup page and is unable to create an account.  I'm lost as to what else I could try to debug this issue.  Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

will happen if you apply 'in' on strings and not on objects
i.e.

```
if ('2' in '.@.') { }
```

To find the source of the error, use the following error handling code

```
window.onerror=function(msg,url,line) {
    console.log("window.error: " + msg + ", url=" + url  +", line="+line);
};
```

if you need deeper insight into your code, then try out jsHybugger - an open source javascript debugger for android apps - http://www.jshybugger.org